# How to assign a new value for class variable from class methods?

Tags: python, oop, object

```
x = int(input("enter x:"))
class hello:
    var = x

h = hello()

print(hello.var)
```

Test run:

```
enter x:15
15
```

How to access the static variable from the methods of the class? I'm stuck at this one

Comment: If i understood ur question correctly , the possible solution is passing x in hello constructor or another better way is define update (value_x) method and passing X value to this method

Comment: What have you already tried, and how didn't it work? Please [edit] to clarify. At the moment, the question in the title, the question in the body, and the code don't really match, so it's unclear what exactly you're trying to do. See [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class method to set class variables

```
x = int(input("enter x:"))

class hello:
    var = x

    @classmethod
    def set_var(cls, value):
        cls.var = value

h = hello()
print(hello.var, h.var)
h.set_var('I am new var')
print(hello.var, h.var)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `hello.var` to have a value, then you can assign something to it:

```
class hello:
    var = None

h = hello()
x = int(input("enter x:"))
h.var = x
print(hello.var)
```

Comment: This is not the way I am looking for I want to access the class variables using methods.I found the answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/62119468/13442749 .... Thanks tho!!!!